# Stream Chat expo default Message List showing warning VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, getstream-io, getstream-chat

I have implemented a sample stream-chat-expo react native application using this tutorial https://getstream.io/chat/react-native-chat/tutorial/, but I have a channel with more than 100 messages and when I scroll up and down , it shows VirtualizedList: You have a large list that is slow to update , No Custom components used still showing that VirtualizedList is slow to update.

I tried this simple built in component.

```
import {
  ...
  Channel,
  MessageList,
  MessageInput,
} from 'stream-chat-expo'

...

const ChannelScreen = props => {
  const { channel } = useAppContext();

  return null;
  return (
    <Channel channel={channel}>
      <MessageList />
      <MessageInput />
    </Channel>
  );
};
```

Shouldn't this be optimized or do I need to somehow implement my own Paging for MessageList component ?